# What is the efficient way to broadcast message?

Tags: python, sockets

In simple console chat application using sockets only without threads, in which a client sends a message to server, and server receives it and then broadcast message to all client sockets, but all clients are blocked by `message = input(f'{my_username} > ')` therefore all clients need to hit `Enter` (as empty message) to receive message sent from server.

Is there an efficient way to fix this issue without using threads since all clients are blocked by `input` in `while loop`

Simple example of client could be:

```
while True:
    # HERE where each client is stopped by input
    # Wait for user to input a message
    msg= input(f'{USERNAME} > ')

    # If message is not empty - send it
    if msg:
    # send message if not empty

    # if not means receiving anything from server
    ....
```

Comment: https://www.dabeaz.com/generators/

Comment: http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/